# How to test an openshift application on local host

Tags: localhost, openshift

I recently start playing with Openshift and I am wondering if there is a way to deploy ( test) your application on local host before you upload it on openshift. 
Thing is that every time I make change on the code, it takes some time to push it to openshift and check if it works.

Google app engine SDK  ( for Eclipse), for example, includes a web server application (app engine simulator) that allows you to test your app locally before you deploy on google.

thnx
Fotis

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are several options actually (assuming you're creating java projects):

1) deploy it on a local jboss as7: this is completely valid since the runtimes that are offered on OpenShift differ in no way from what you can run locally / in a hosted environment. What's specific to OpenShift is the deployment process. It basically is a git push which triggers a maven build on the PaaS.

2) use the rpms/liveCD: OpenShift is also available as linux rpm packages and as virtual machine appliance (you may run with virtualbox, vm player etc).
You'll find more details here: http://blog.jebpages.com/archives/run-openshift-origin-from-livecd-and-make-it-stick/ and here: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/wiki/build-your-own-paas-from-the-openshift-origin-livecd-using-liveinst

3) remote debug the application that is running on OpenShift: You'll find the details here:
https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2012/06/27/deploy-from-eclipse-to-openshift-in-a-breeze

Comment: The JBoss environment on OpenShift differs from a local one in a few trivial ways, i think; OpenShift will pick up a server configuration from `.openshift/config/standalone.xml`, whereas a local JBoss will need it in `configuration`. I assume there is a deploy script somewhere in OpenShift that pulls it out and puts it in the right place (OpenShift builds a JBoss server at `~/AppName/jbossas-7/standalone/`), but i don't know if there's an easy way to do that locally.

Comment: if you really want to run jboss as at 100% as it is run on OpenShift, you can tell your local jbossas-7 to run the config file that's used on OpenShift: 
Simply pass it this config file with the command line parameter --server-config (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters)

Comment: Is there anything else that is different on the OpenShift machines? I had a look through the shell script which starts JBoss there, and there's a lot of stuff going on, but nothing struck me as immediately significant.