# Testing spring openshift application locally

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jboss, openshift

I have an application running on Openshift. It works fine, but testing is difficult because i have to push every little thing to openshift and wait for all the building and restarting to see the changes.

So i am trying to find a way to test the application locally. 
Another guy asked the same thing here: [How to test an openshift application on local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222924/how-to-test-an-openshift-application-on-local-host), but i am wondering if an easier solution exists.

I used the quickstart project here http://github.com/openshift/spring-eap6-quickstart.git to start it. So basically it is a Spring application using Hibernate.

What i have in mind to have two sets of configuration files (`persistence.xml` etc.) in the project, one for local Tomcat server and one for Jboss eap and 
change `web.xml` according to the server i want to deploy to. Is this doable? Looks so simple, i am afraid of any surprise problems before changing the 
project.

Comment: Suggestions from adietisheim are probably best and your approach also sounds good. Give it a try with a simple project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how i ended up doing. I renamed the original `web.xml` file, with something like `web-openshift.xml`. When projects are built in OpenShift, the maven `openshift` profile is used. You can find it in your `<profiles>` section in pom.xml. So i added a line to my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
         ....
           <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web-openshift.xml</webXml>  <!--add this-->
```

This makes the `maven-war-plugin` to use the `web-openshift.xml` file as the web deployment descriptor when building the war. Then i added a `web.xml` file, which will be used for my local build. In those files you configure your servlets with:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/jboss-as-spring-mvc-context.xml</param-value>
```

So by changing the `<param-value>` in my two `web.xml` files, I was able to configure Spring and Hibernate in different ways.

Then I added the jars marked as `<provided>` in `pom.xml` to the `\lib` directory of my Tomcat installation. Now i am able to deploy and run the application both to OpenShift and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fast connection you can run your app on a local server, and let the persistence.xml point to the openshift db.  To access the db remotely you will have to use port forwarding(https://www.openshift.com/blogs/getting-started-with-port-forwarding-on-openshift ).  You will need to setup the rhc client (https://www.openshift.com/developers/rhc-client-tools-install) and run the rhc port forward client to access the database. 
You can then point just run the eclipse project on your tomcat server, and it will ( with persistence.xml I assume you are using a db) connect to the database. Any code changes will be treated like any other tomcat project.
There is no need to have a separate web.xml for most case (unless you have some openshift specific configurations).

You can even use tools like Toad to connect to the db if you want.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, but i think i will still need two different configurations for persistence. For example for local development i need to set `hibernate.show_sql=true`

Answer (score 0):

In an app that I have running both locally and on Openshift, I used the persistent app-root/data folder to store any specific OpenShift configuration.

In my web.xml, I am including the properties as follows:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${user.home}/app-root/data/configuration.properties"/>
```

If you're managing sensitive configuration properties like usernames and passwords, Openshift's env variables can go a long way. For example, you can put the following properties in your pom.xml, under the openshift profile:

```
<properties>
  <db.username>${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_USERNAME}</db.username>
  <db.password>${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_PASSWORD}</db.password>                    
  <db.connectionURL>postgresql://${env.OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_HOST}:5432/${env.PGDATABASE}</db.connectionURL>
</properties>
```

To retrieve your database connection properties from the Openshift environment variables. You can then use maven's resource filtering to put these properties into any files in specific directories like src/main/resources

My own local db connection properties are managed in a profile in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file.

This approach enables me to:

- keep all sensitive properties out of my public code repository
- very simply switch between openshift and local deployment by enabling/disabling maven build profiles.